# Generating SpecFlow's feature.cs files in a different location to the feature files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow

Fairly simple one: I'm trying to make SpecFlow generate feature.cs files, but in a directory I specify and not the default (which is the same directory as the associated feature file). Is this possible?

Comment: The approach suggested by Alski below might work, but I'd like to understand what is driving this need as I have a feeling there may be a different solution to the underlying issue. It feels to me like you have decided on a solution to a problem and want help implementing that solution, when actually reevaluating the root problem might reveal a more appropriate solution that then one you have decided on. It might not, but knowing what the *actual* problem being solved is might help provide a more appropriate solution

Comment: Hi Sam. Basically, we want to separate the feature files from the test code that uses it so they can be in two different repos.

Answer (score 2):

Not by default, but it might be possible.

SpecFlow uses an inbuilt mechanism inside Visual Studio called a custom tool. its a means of automatically performing an action whenever a file changes and is also used in designers (such as the winforms, asp.net etc) which also generate an xxx.designer.cs file. For more details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx

This is controlled by a couple of entries in the .csproj file

```
<None Include="xxx.feature">
   <Generator>SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
   <LastGenOutput>xxx.feature.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

and

```
<Compile Include="xxx.feature.cs">
  <DependentUpon>xxx.feature</DependentUpon>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
</Compile>
```

So as you can see you have all the information you need here to change the file locations and keep the association between them. However I've never tried it, so let us know how you get on.