# How can I generate specflow feature.cs files with msbuild?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, bdd, specflow

I'm trying to use specflow with CI, and it seems wrong to have to check the generated .cs files into source control.

I've tried editing the .csproj file to set `<BeforeBuild>True</BeforeBuild>` in the `Compile` step for the feature.cs file but it seems to make no difference. The only way I can find to regenerate the .feature.cs file is to use visual studio, but I want to use msbuild on the CI build server.

I also tried adding a `AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject` target as described at [specflow doc](http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/) but that also didn't create the .feature.cs files, either with or without the .feature.cs files in the .csproj file.

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691852/generating-specflows-feature-cs-files-in-a-different-location-to-the-feature-fi) suggests reading "Specifying Custom Build Tools" on MSDN but I couldn't see anything helpful on there. The [schema definition for msbuild on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx) doesn't even mention the `Compile` element AFAICT.)

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions at 
http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/, but there are some missing steps.

1. Set the SpecFlowTasksPath property to the location of specflow.exe
2. Import TechTalk.SpecFlow.tasks
3. Import TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets

These paths should be relative paths, mine point to the NuGet packages\ folder where I reference SpecFlow for my project.

Additonally, I added a step in the AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject target to move the generated files to a known location so they can be easily reviewed. This folder is ignored in my GIT repository.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SpecFlowTasksPath>..\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\specflow.exe</SpecFlowTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="..\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.tasks"  Condition="Exists('..\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.tasks')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets')" />
  <Target Name="AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject">
    <Move SourceFiles="@(SpecFlowGeneratedFiles)" DestinationFolder="Features.Generated" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- include any files that specflow generated into the compilation of the project -->
      <Compile Include="Features.Generated\**\*.cs">
        <Visible>true</Visible>
        <!-- the generated files can be hidden in Visual Studio -->
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You find the documentation for generating the code behind files with MSBuild here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention I had looked at that page but it had no effect; I will update my question.

Comment: Ok, strange. That should work. I have done it multiple times in various projects and in SpecFlow itself. See here for it: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs.csproj#L206

Comment: Important is the <Import> here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Tests/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Specs.csproj#L195

Comment: I tried adding the import and it still doesn't generate the .cs files, it sounds like it is a little more than "add only one line to the end of project file" as the doc states! I'll grab your github and have a look to see what it is doing differently to my project.

Comment: FYI, the links above point to the master branch of @AndreasWillich 's repo and the line numbers are off after additonal commits. As he says, you are looking for the <Import> lines, specifically the ones that import echTalk.SpecFlow.tasks & echTalk.SpecFlow.targets. I found there are still some additonal steps, see my answer.